# How to change the minSdkVersion in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I tried to change it in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shubham.warning"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-             rules.pro'
    }
    }
  }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0-beta1'
 }
```

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.shubham.warning" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".Warning" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>

  </manifest>
```

But whenever I try to test it on my avd it shows the following error:

> minSdk(API 23, N preview)!=deviceSdk(api 22)

[image]

i have changed it in builg.gradle
but it still showing apk 23 in the error

Comment: check your menifest file if you have apply there something else

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this yet? 
Tools > Android > Sync Project With Gradle Files

Also, 
Build > Clean Project 
Build > Rebuild Project

If still not working, try to manually restart Android Studio.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you still see the same issue coming up.